# moving or coping an email using doveadm

Tags: email

I am tring to copy some email (using doveadm) having the code 7F7029018730 in email header FROM email user spam@mydomain.com (INBOX)  to account info@domain2.com (INBOX.spambox) .

I tried using these ways

```
doveadm copy -u info@domain2.com INBOX.spambox user spam@mydomain.com search 7F7029018730

doveadm copy -u info@domain2.com INBOX.spambox user spam@mydomain.com search ALL 7F7029018730

doveadm copy -u info@domain2.com INBOX.spambox user spam@mydomain.com 7F7029018730
```

none of them works, any help please ?

I have [read](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Move) docs and [Link](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/SearchQuery), but I do not understand where I am failing.

Thanks